# Pass content to the inner view {{outlet}}

Tags: ember.js

I have simple Ember app with Ember Data (powered by Rails). I have created these routes:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('bands', function () {
        this.route('new');
        this.resource('band', {path: ':band_id'}, function() {
            this.route('edit');
        });
    });
});
```

Then, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/#/bands/23/edit`, I'd like to see the values of the object with ID 23, like this:

```
<div>name: {{name}}</div>
{{! should output "name: Pavel" }}
```

However, when I put that code into `band/edit.hbs`, the application displays only "name: ", without any value. I have figured out it's because the content is not passed to the inner view. When I put the same piece of code directly to `band.hbs`, everything works as expected. Where am I doing a mistake? How can I pass the content object to the controller? (If possible, I'd like to have generated as much controllers as I can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to at least define the the route for BandEdit:

```
App.BandEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('band'));
  }
});
```

If you need to you could always add the model to a transaction before returning it.

You could also do this by referencing the parentController from within the BandEdit Controller, but that seems like it would be a less elegant way to solve this.

Comment: Well, there seems to be tiny problem with your solution. Now, when I refresh at `http://localhost:3000/#/bands/23/edit`, nothing gets displayed. When I delete `BandEditRoute` (so I let Ember to generate it for me), it works fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `context` has been changed by your inner view *(the context will now be the view itself)*, but the view will have access to the `BandEditController` and its associated model, so if you **always** reference the `model` first then Ember will know what you're after: `{{model.name}}`/`{{model.genre}}`.

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ84L/

(Use in conjunction with Andre's answer, because if you're not even passing through the `model` to your `outlet` then it's unusable.)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you. I keep trying to answer your questions, and one day I'll have some luck!